# Motion event error on ImageButton click

Tags: java, android, pointers, events, motion

```
public class AddActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
String[] info =  new String[11];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_layout);                
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView keyString = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.keyString);
    TextView site1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.site1);
    TextView site2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.site2);
    TextView site3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.site3);
    ImageButton submit = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    ImageButton add1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add1);
    ImageButton add2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add2);
    ImageButton add3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add3);

    submit.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    add1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    add2.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    add3.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    int id = v.getId();
    switch(id){
    case R.id.submit:{
        submitEntry(info);
        break;
    }
    case R.id.add1:{
        add2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        site2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    }
    }
}
}
```

This is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/key_string"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/keyString"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/site_string"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/add1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/site1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/url_hint"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/add2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/site2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/url_hint"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/add3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/site3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/url_hint"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
       <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/submit_buttom" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the XML. The add1, add2, add3 and submit ImageButtons are all in a ScrollView.

When I press the add1 ImageButton, I want the add2 and site2 ImageButtons to become visible but instead, it throws the following error.

> Motion event has invalid pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: All the findViewById() calls are in the onClick() method because a NullPointerExeption is thrown if I call them in the onCreate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those `findViewById`calls in `onClick`don't make sense. Not sure why you are getting a null pointer exception calling them in `onCreate`.`onClick` is never called in this instance because nothing in the creation of the Activity is assigning the buttons to look at your `onClick` method; the buttons will default to having no listener assigned. It also doesn't look like a good idea to use the Activity as the onClickListener as well.

Your code should look something like this:

```
public class AddActivity extends Activity {
// https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html
// info -> mInfo; non-public, non-static field!
String[] mInfo =  new String[11];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_layout);

    TextView keyString = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.keyString);
    TextView site1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.site1);
    TextView site2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.site2);
    TextView site3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.site3);
    Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    ImageButton add1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add1);
    ImageButton add2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add2);
    ImageButton add3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add3);

    add1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        add2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        site2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        submitEntry(mInfo);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Also, I think I got an error when declaring it all in the onCreate() because in the XML, the submit is a Button whereas I declared it as an ImageButton in the AddActivity class. Just a heads up for others!

Answer (score 0):

The findViewById() calls and especially the setOnClickListener() calls should have been inside the onCreate(). With setOnClickListener() inside the onClick() i doubt the onClick was ever called.

We would need more logs to find the exact issue.