# Motion event has invalid pointer count 0 >> On opening/ closing/ selecting in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, motionevent

I get this error if I do anything with my navigation drawer.

```
Motion event has invalid pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16.
```

This error doesn't crash my activity. But just floods my log. Below is the activity. The adapter is custom adapter having image and text in a row.

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
private ListView navList;
private NavAdapter navAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    navList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_list);
    navAdapter = new NavAdapter(this);
    navList.setAdapter(navAdapter);
    navList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.opendrawer, R.string.closedrawer);

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    navList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    String menuItem = (((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.drawerTV)).getText().toString());
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(menuItem);
}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411401/motion-event-error-on-imagebutton-click?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to find the cause of the error but does not provide the solution.